# XmlSerializer & Activator.CreateInstance()

Tags: c#, serialization, activator

Okay, we all know that it is not possible to use the XmlSerializer for classes without a parameterless constuctor as the deserializer will create the object and set all properties. However, by using Activator.CreateInstance() one can instanciate classes without a parameterless constructor. For example we could instanciate the following class:

```
public class Foo
{
    public Foo(string bar){}
}
```

That class can easily be instanciated with the Activator:

```
Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Foo),"some string");
```

Unfortunantely 'Foo' cannot be serialized using the XmlSerializer as it has no parameterless constructor. Why is there no way to use the XmlSerializer like that:

```
new XmlSerializer(typeof(Foo)).Deserialize(stream,"some string");
```

Of course I could implement my own Serializer that simply will store the type and all properites & fields of an object and then will use the Activator to instanciate the object and set the previously stores properties. The question is: would that make sense? I guess there must be a strong reason against because otherwise that would be implemented already, right?!?

Comment: Note that there should be "strong reason *for*", not "against" for feature to be implemented - see [Minus 100 points](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericgu/archive/2004/01/12/57985.aspx). Something that covers very narrow case (like you suggest) rarely can get enough "points" to be implemented.

Comment: Personally, I'd argue that reinventing the wheel is not nearly as fun as using an existing, polished solution, such as protobuf-net, which lacks these limitations.

Comment: @Haney - is not it other way around? Reinventing wheel is most of the fun... Otherwise why everyone implement they own logging framework...

Comment: @Haney steady now, you'll make me blush...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I suppose it depends if you're a "tinkerer" at heart. But writing a new serializer when many, many working alternatives exist seems relatively redundant. And Marc - no bias involved. The only reason I recommend protobuf-net is A) I've used it in past projects very successfully and 2) it's faster, easier, and more flexible than `XmlSerializer`. I've been bitten so many times by `XmlSerializer` that I fear it.

Answer (score 1):

`XmlSerializer` works via C# code-generation and dynamic compilation; because it uses the C# compiler, it is necessary that the code it generates would compile - noting that it must follow the rules as a separate assembly (no `internal` or `private` access).

Basically, it wants to use `new Foo()`, because it literally emits the C# code `"new Foo()"` which is fed to the compiler.

Yes, it could have chosen to use a different instantiation technique, but: `new Foo()` is the authors chose to go with - and it is a reasonable default.

Some other serializers choose to use `Activator`, and others still use sneaky IL techniques that provide direct access to non-public methods without any indirection.